# How to make multiple separate groups Mongoose aggregations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Here is working example if I want to take just `types` that have `offer` `false`

```
aggregate([
            {
                "$match": {}
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$type",
                    "count": {
                        "$sum": {
                            "$cond": {
                                if : {
                                    $eq: ["$offer", false]
                                },
                                then: 1,
                                else: 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        ]
```

But what if I want to take also `types` where `offer` is true?

So current result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "product",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "event",
      "count": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

But I need something like this:

```
{
  "data": [
  offer: {
    {
      "_id": "product",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "event",
      "count": 2
    }
},
  nooffer: {
    {
      "_id": "product",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "_id": "event",
      "count": 1
    }
}
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is your mongo server version ? Can you add a sample doc from your collection and expected json output ?

Comment: `3.2` Collection is simple I have `offer` and `type` offer is boolean, type can be 'event' or `product`. I need to group by type and take sum of types where offer is true and false.

Comment: Edited question